# Passing func inline as a parameter (eg a => a....)

Tags: c#

How can I supply a func to a method, so I could write something like:

```
MethodTest(a => a.IsAltTagAvailable);
```

Where the signature of this method takes a func which returns an object (say HtmlImage) when the condition is met (basically just a predicate).

Edit: I need to pass the type I will be working on as T (Parameter). I forgot to do this, how clumsy!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A *predicate* tends to return `bool`, not an object. What are you going to return when the condition isn't met? Given your example, you don't really mean the function *returns* an object - you mean it *takes* an object and returns a `bool`.

Note that if you're going to have a parameter in the lambda expression, you'll need to use a delegate which takes parameters too.

We really need more information before giving a definitive answer, but you might want something like:

```
void MethodTest(Func<HtmlImage, bool> predicate)
```

or

```
void MethodTest(Predicate<HtmlImage> predicate)
```

(Personally I like the descriptive nature of using a named delegate, but others prefer to use `Func`/`Action` for almost everything.)

That's assuming that the type of input is fixed. If not, you might want to make it a generic method:

```
void MethodTest<T>(Predicate<T> predicate)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void MethodTest(Func<HtmlImage> func) {

}
```

Comment: @Stefan: based on my understanding of the question he wanted to "Where the signature of this method takes a func which returns an object" which is contradictory to the Lambda he wrote inside his code.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void MethodTest(Func<HtmlImage> delegate)
{
 //do what you want
}
```

OR:

```
public delegate HtmlImageTagHandler(HtmlImage image);


public HtmlImage MethodTest(HtmlImageTagHandler handler, HtmlImage image)
{
  return handler(image) == true ? image : null;
}
```

use:

```
MethodTest(a => a.IsAltTagAvailable, a);
```

Comment: Yes there seems to be a little contradiction in his question...as to what he wants.

Answer (score 1):

```
void MethodTest(Func<HtmlImage, object> func) 
{

}
```

`HtmlImage` is the argument of the function (`x`), `object` the return value, you could take the concrete type if you want to specify it.

```
void MethodTest(Func<HtmlImage, bool> func)
```

Which is a predicate:

```
void MethodTest(Predicate<HtmlImage> func)
```

To make it fully generic, replace HtmlImage with a generic argument:

```
void MethodTest<T>(Predicate<T> func)
```